# Aspect @annotation(PutMapping) not working

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspect

I have the following code in my aspect class.

```
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.api.webservice.controller.*.*(..)) " +
            "&& (@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping) || @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping) || @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping))")
    public void pointCut() {}

    @Around("pointCut()")
    public Object handleMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
         ......
    }
```

The `"PostMapping"` and `"DeleteMapping"` both worked as expected (handleMethod() was hit). But `"PutMapping"` seems not working cause handleMethod() was not hit when I fired a "Put" restful call through my postman. My method prototype are

```
    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Entity create(@Valid @RequestBody Entity entity) {
        ...
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public Entity update(@PathVariable String id, @Valid @RequestBody Entity entity) {
        ...
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void deleteEntityById(@PathVariable String id) {
        ...
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your problem is not reproduceable because it is not an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The root cause is probably in the code you are not showing. Nobdy can do more than speculate. You do not even show class and package names. You also did not mention if the `update(..)` method was triggered by your REST call. Did you see it in the logs or so?

Comment: @kriegaex, the update and create / delete are in the same controller file. That's why I didn't mention the package here after I said post / delete works. Also, the update(..) method was able to be triggered by my REST call. It just skip the method in aspect.

Comment: I repeat: The problem must be in the part of code you do **not** show. If the problem was where you think it is, you would have found it by now. But as you wish - if you don't like to share more details, go figure it out yourself.

Comment: You are right. @kriegaex. It seems the cause is because I name the endpoints as "events". After I change it to "activities", it works fine. Still, I don't know why is that? why post and delete works but update doesn't like the endpoint name. But many thanks.